# Why Highcharts not returning the proper date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Hello i'm developing a chart similar to [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/e12xLbe1/).
But in that chart the dates are displayed which are not actual dates `1 Jan, 1970`
And tried using `formatter()` also returns the first on date not full date and also removes the HTML and strings which i concatenated while returning.

Comment: check here on one way to do dates  -- http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/datetimelabelformats/

Comment: That is for datetime, my chart is heatmaps

Comment: @Tasos can you please check that fiddle for any suggestions?

Comment: **'{point.x:%e %b, %Y} {point.y}:00: <b>{point.value}'**. I understood that point.x represents the date and point.y represents the month. So you have to format the date from all the date values.

Comment: @allu that's where i am stucked ..

Comment: And if i use `formatter` for that then it returns the date only no full format and also removes other strings like `<b>kQh</b>` and so on...

Comment: Can u show the ``formatter`` code?

Comment: `formatter:function () {

  return ' ' + HighCharts.dateFormat('%e %b, %Y', new Date(dataYear, this.y, this.x)) + ' ' + this.y + ':00<b>' + this.value +' kWh</b>';

}`

Comment: in that it returns  only date and `this.value` and other stuff is removed. I have taken dataYear from the data given in chart only date and month is used.

Comment: It returns incorrectly because you are trying to use a *date formatting* function on a value that is *not a date*. Your **point.x** is an integer between 1 and 31. Which, as a date in javascript returns as between 1 and 31 **milliseconds** after the start of 1970.

Comment: @jlbriggs that's why I have used 3 different values there 
The first one is point.x , point.y and charYear for full date. But still not able to get full date. 

see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/e12xLbe1/) and what should be changed in that so the proper date is shown.

Comment: @jlbriggs `formatter()` also removes the extra strings like in the above function shown. Why it is happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of approaches taking place in the fiddle, post, and comment thread.

Here's one that works:

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
    var month    = this.point.y;
    var day      = this.point.x;
    var dataDate = new Date(dataYear, month, day); //set the date object; dataYear predefined
    return  '<b>Power Generated</b><br/>'
           +Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %b, %Y', dataDate) //format the date object
           +': <b>'+this.point.value +' kWh</b>';
    }
}
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/e12xLbe1/12/

Obviously, you can edit the strings in whichever way you want to.

There are a number of reasons that things were not workign with earlier versions, including:

- the month/date being swapped in the `new Date()` declaration.
- calling `HighCharts` instead of `Highcharts`
- calling `this.value` instead of `this.point.value`

If you have more specific questions about something not working, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you @jlbriggs. One more question please.

I am not using data directly via js function like in the fiddle, but instead i want to add **php**, **mysql** integration but seems like `json_encode()` returning JSON is not working w/ and w/o `DataLoader` plugin as well as simple ajax. What could be the problem? 

i have also used `parseInt(number, 10)` for parsing integers but still chart is not generated.

Comment: I would start another question for that. In general, check your values at every stage in your processing; make sure that they are returning in the right format, that numbers aren't being passed as strings, etc. Proper nesting of arrays/objects is important.